# Counting values based on varying dates in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, data-analysis

I am having a problem that requires me to count the number of observations in the response column (1s and 0s only) grouped by IDs and based on varying reference dates. I am thinking of using dplyr summarise as a solution but I could not make it work if I take into consideration the said dates.

Sample Data:

```
CustomerID   AccountID     OpenDate     Response
   AAA         456        2020-01-01        1
   AAA         456        2020-01-03        1
   AAA         456        2020-01-05        1
   BBB         789        2020-02-01        1
   BBB         789        2020-02-22        0
   BBB         789        2020-03-01        1
```

Desired Count Result:

```
CustomerID   AccountID     OpenDate       Count
   AAA         456        2020-01-01        1
   AAA         456        2020-01-03        2
   AAA         456        2020-01-05        3
   BBB         789        2020-02-01        1
   BBB         789        2020-02-22        1
   BBB         789        2020-03-01        2
```

Notice that as the dates go farther, the response count increases because it took into consideration the movement of days.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(CustomerID) %>% mutate(Count =cumsum(Count))`

Comment: for context: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/17-tips-tricks/57-dplyr-how-to-add-cumulative-sums-by-groups-into-a-data-framee/

Comment: Hi, I tried doing this but for some reason the count is not accurate. I think it is not taking into account the date that well

Comment: Hi, fixed it by adding arrange(OpenDate). Thanks